# How to connect to another linux machine from Ubuntu in Virtual box

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a `Raspberry pi`.

I have installed `Ubuntu 16.04` in my windows 10 laptop using `VirtualBox`.

I have connected an Ethernet cable between `Raspberry pi` and to my laptop.

IP address of pi is `169.254.1.93` and IP address in my windows 10 is `169.254.220.89`. I can ping the pi using `cmd` in windows.

Now I need to connect the pi to Ubuntu running on Virtual box in my laptop.

The connection settings in Ubuntu is dynamic but I am not able to ping my pi.

Do I need to set static IP address.

How can I ping my pi?

Answer (score 2):

The source of the problem seems to be in the Virtual Host network definition in the VirtualBox configuration.

One simple solution might be to use a Bridge Adapter in virtualbox.

In the HOST (Windows) Virtual box setting choose:

- Settings for your machine
- Network
- Adapter 1
- Select Bridged Adapter.

See below Picture:

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried to do that. While selecting Bridged Adapter, it shows 3 options, wireless, wired, virtual box internal adapter. Which one should I choose. I selected wired connection and on ubuntu it keep on connecting but fails everytime. No connection

Comment: @Yaron I believe the OP will have to also run `ifconfig` in VM so OP can get the assigned `IP Add` which will be used in the other device, and should modify any firewall (if present) settings.

Comment: @Yaron I chose the wired as I have wired connection but still it didnt connected. I think I was using the wrong way. What I have done now is I have connected pi to my router and connected my laptop to router too. So everything is on the same network and I can ping now. Earlier I was using direect cable between pi and laptop

Comment: @SAndrew - Happy to hear that it works now. Did the bridge mode helped you?

Comment: @Yaron No on the bridged network it was not connecting. I am using the NAT